# Use DefaultSSLSocketFactory in WildFly/CXF Webservice client

Tags: java, cxf, wildfly-9, cxf-client, jbossws

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I'm using the following :

- WildFly 9
- jbossws-cxf-*-5.0.0.Final
- cxf-core-3.0.5

and I am dealing with an integration issue with a partner endpoint related to SNI in the HTTPS handshake.  Following along with another site ([here](http://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html?m=1)) I have been able to create a custom SSLSocketFactory and set that as the default SSLSocketFactory, but then I ran into the issue where CXF does not use the default SSLSocketFactory([here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2693)). With that I have not found a way to inform CXF to use the default SSLSocketFactory through configuration.

By debugging I was able to set the httpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier on the TLSClientParameters to true and confirmed that this resolves the issue. I have also seen a number of posts that imply that this value can be set via a configuration file(JBoss WS config or CXF config) or as a startup parameter, but I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Has anyone else been able to accomplish this and if so can you share how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only answer I could find to this particular issue was pretty brute force/ugly, but here goes in hopes it may save someone some pain later.

1. I created a custom SSLSocketFactory and set that as the default at
   startup.
2. This factory will return a custom connection
   implementation that extends the CXF extend the SOAPConnectionImpl
   that will set setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory to
   true on the TLSClientParameters.
3. This is set on the URLConnectionHTTPConduit in turn
4. Lastly I had to use a ThreadLocal class to hold the host name which is used by the custom SSLSocketFactory